# What are these strange numbers enclosed in a dotted square?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-365

[image]
I don't know what this strange numbering could be

Comment: Right click one of the "40"'s and select "Toggle field codes". What do you see now?

Comment: If you have python installed: `python -c  "import os;os.system('');print('\x1b[40m TEST \x1b[49m TEST ')"` - change 40 to 41 and the text background is red, 40 is a dark color (possibly black).

Comment: Sorry for not commenting, I have already done it and they are not fields.

Comment: So, from where did you COPY the text you pasted?

Comment: I suggest providing a link to a sample document with the problem.

Comment: Small inline images? If you select one and right-click, which menu does Word display? Personally I would save a small document with one of these characters in XML format and inspect the XML.

Comment: These numbers can be found by searching for "eumot"
https://1drv.ms/w/s!Ah7fIrE9mm7WrFkxz5KMtk0Vtk_S?e=6yXkLN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a "Page Number Block", which is described in the ISO Specification for the .docx format (ISO/IEC 29500-1 Fundamentals and Markup Language Reference) as follows:

```
17.3.3.22 pgNum (Page Number Block)
This element specifies the presence of a page number block at the current location in the run content. A page
number block is a non-editable region of text which shall display the current page using ascending decimal
numbers. [Note: The page number block is a legacy construct used for compatibility with older word processors,
and should not be produced unless it was consumed while reading a document – it is recommended that the
PAGENUM field is used in its place. end note]
A page number block shall be displayed using ascending decimal numbers, regardless of the languages specified
in the parent run’s lang property (§17.3.2.20).
[Example: Consider a WordprocessingML run with the following run content:
<w:r>
<w:t xml:space="preserve">This is the current page: </w:t>
<w:pgNum />
</w:r>
This run specifies that a page number block must be placed after the text string literal This is the current
page: in the document. Assuming that this content is on the first page, this run would be displayed as follows:
This is the current page: 1
```

(The Word Open XML code for the "run" starting with one of these chars and your first "eumot" is

```
<w:r><w:pgNum/></w:r><w:r><w:t>eumot</w:t></w:r>
```

)

I don't know what construct in your source text would result in this, but if you need to know, and it's an HTML source, it should be reasonably easy to look at the underlying HTML code.

If you just need to get rid of them, selecting the character and using Edit->Replace to replace them by (nothing) does seem to remove some of them, but not all. **EDIT:** If you use VBA and AscW(Selection) to find the character code of these characters, it's 0. So I tried using advanced Find/Replace, *without* using wildcards, to find `^0` and replace by (nothing). That does seem to work.

[[Because of that finding, you probably don't need to use the sort of thing I suggested below:

You might be able to do this, but when I tried it, I saw a message that some custom content controls would not be saved, so this may not work.

It's possible to extract the XML document from the .docx, remove all the pgNum elements, then put it back, but I don't have time to describe that procedure right now or find a good link that would help.

- Save as Word XML Document (*.xml)
- Open in Notepad, if you can (it's a long document!), or another plain
  text editor.
- Replace `<:pgNum/>` by nothing
- Save
- reopen in Word
  ]]

Comment: Thank you very much, Johnson.
How are these PageNum blocks inserted? Or better, how could they have been inserted in this document?

Comment: @wordexperto.com I don't know, but if you were  copying from another format, e.g. web page, perhaps another Word processor format, or even a document created in an old Version of Word, that might lead to an explanation. In particular, I wonder if .odf/ .odt documents use a construct that Word translates into pgNum elements.

Comment: Thank you so much for everything.

Answer (score 0):

This same issue happened in several of my team's Word documents.  The documents were housed on SharePoint, and not only did the page numbers appear, but other random changes, both in formatting and content were shown as tracked at the same time.  These changes were capitalization changes (MPa to mPa, pp to Pp), capitalizing random words, and replacing several characters at a time with a lowercase l.

From what I can tell, these all happened in a time proximate to a global (or global, stepwise) find/replace. However, the find/replace queries had nothing to do with the changes made.  I'd love to know what could cause it. These documents are all mature and copy/paste from another doesn't seem like a likely cause.